# Rails, Angular 2 - importing angular drag and drop list - Reference error: angular is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, typescript

I've just started using Angular 2 with Rails 5.1.

When i try to import the [angular-drag-and-drop-list](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) in my CategoriesModule, i get an error in my rails application:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

The drag-and-drop file is loaded, and this error is trickered from the bottom of it:

```
...
})(angular.module('dndLists', []));
```

What am i doing wrong? I've installed the package with npm and now it's added in my package.json as:

```
"angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "^2.1.0",
```

Here is my module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CategoriesIndexComponent  } from './categories_index.component';

import { dndLists } from 'angular-drag-and-drop-lists';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   CategoriesIndexComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    dndLists,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ CategoriesIndexComponent ]
})
export class CategoriesIndexModule{ }
```

So Angular is not being loadet before the file?

How can this happen?

I would appreciate any help.